# Inclusion between two sets

Tags: integration, elementary-set-theory

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space and $\varphi\in L^\infty(X,\mu)$

\begin{equation*}
A=\left\{\left[\int_X|\varphi|^2|f|^2d\mu\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}\,;\,f\in L^2(X,\mu),\;\|f\|_2=1\right\},
\end{equation*}
and

\begin{equation*}
B=\left\{\int_X\varphi|f|^2d\mu\,;\,f\in L^2(X,\mu),\;\|f\|_2=1\right\}.
\end{equation*}

> I'm trying to prove that $A\subseteq B$.

Let $\alpha\in A$, then
$$ \alpha=\left[\int_X|\varphi|^2|f|^2d\mu\right]^{\frac{1}{2}},$$
for some $f\in L^2(X,\mu)$ with $\|f\|_2=1$. Then,
$$ \alpha^2=\int_X|\varphi|^2|f|^2d\mu.$$

Comment: These sets don't really make sense. You might want to include $\varphi$ into their definition?